# sqlite3 db.close() called before db.serialized() finishes

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

i have a sqlite3 nested query case. Was hoping to push each query result to a json array and return it back.
But always get "Error: SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed" for the 2nd select call.
Seems the db.close() gets called before the 2nd query.

Why is this, i thought serialize can take care of this. How to fix it please ?

```
var getMyDbInfo = function(callback) {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database("MyDB.sqlite3");

    db.serialize(function() {

        var myJsonObj = {};

        db.each("select * from Table1",
            function(err, row) {
                console.log("\n---- 0 ----\n");
                // calculate doorId from row
                doorId = ...

                db.all("select * from Table2 where ID=" + doorId,
                       function(err, row2) {
                           console.log("---- 6 ----\n");
                           if(err) {
                               console.log("-- ERR: " + err);
                           } else {
                               console.log(row2);
                               var myJsonElem = {ID:row.ID,
                                   DoorName: row2.DoorName,
                                   TimeSpec: row2.TimeSpec };

                               myJsonObj.data.push(myJsonElem);
                           }
                       }
               );
            }
        );
        callback(null, myJsonObj);
    });

    console.log("---- 10 ----\n");
    db.close();

};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `db.all()` call is **nested** in the callback function of `db.each()`. [Per the docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow), `db.serialize()` only serializes calls made directly in the `db.serialize()` callback function. As far as `db.serialize()` is concerned, its job is done as soon as the callback for `db.each()` is called, as there are no more inline calls to make, and so `db.close()` is executed.

A solution here - Get rid of `db.serialize()` since you're only calling `db.each()` inside it, and use a second "[completion](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete)" callback function for `db.each()` that calls `db.close()` after `db.each()` has run through all rows.

If need to make more DB calls after `db.each()`, add a `db.serialize()` *inside* the `db.each()` completion callback and continue from there.

```js
var getMyDbInfo = function(callback) {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database("MyDB.sqlite3");

    var myJsonObj = {};

    db.each("select * from Table1",
        function(err, row) {
            console.log("\n---- 0 ----\n");
            // calculate doorId from row
            doorId = ...

            db.all("select * from Table2 where ID=" + doorId,
                    function(err, row2) {
                        console.log("---- 6 ----\n");
                        if(err) {
                            console.log("-- ERR: " + err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(row2);
                            var myJsonElem = {ID:row.ID,
                                DoorName: row2.DoorName,
                                TimeSpec: row2.TimeSpec };

                            myJsonObj.data.push(myJsonElem);
                        }
                    }
            );
        },
        function (err, rows) {
            callback(null, myJsonObj);
            db.close();
            console.log("---- 10 ----\n");
        }
    );

};
```